# ASP.Net hosts support Sync Framework? - Sync SQL data and document files with Hosted ASP.Net web application?

Tags: sql, microsoft-sync-framework

I need to sync the following items between anapplicaiton on my LAN and a hosted ASP.net/SQL web app:

SQL data (5 tables)
Document files

From what I've read, I believe that the Sync Framework is the best choise for that, however I can not find a shared hosting vendor who supports Sync Framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if your LAN based applicaton can access your hosted SQL, you can have all the Sync Framework components on the client application side alone. you only need the Sync Framework components on the hosting side if you plan on executing part of the synchronization code on the host side.

Comment: if you can't install Sync Framework on the hosted site, you can have a WCF service in the LAN side that you can call from your hosted app to trigger the sync. so all Sync Framework bits are still on the LAN side.